# Dynamic array heap corruption

Tags: c++, dynamic, corruption, heap-corruption

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix
{
private:
    int _n;
    T* array;
public:
    matrix(): _n(0) 
    {
        array = new T[_n * _n];
    }
    matrix(int n): _n(n)
    {
        if( n < 0 )
            throw "Invalid array size!";
        array = new T[_n * _n];
    }
    ~matrix()
    {
        delete[] array;
    }
    void Set(const int x, const int y,const T val)
    {
        if( ( x<0 || x>_n ) && ( y<0 || y>_n) )
            throw "Invalid index";
        array[x*_n + y] = val;
    }
    T& Get(const int x, const int y)
    {
        if( ( x<0 || x>_n ) && ( y<0 || y>_n) )
            throw "Invalid index";
        return array[x*_n + y];
    }
};
```

and using it this way:

```
matrix<int> k(5);
k.Set(5,5,6);
cout<<k.Get(5,5);
```

The problem is I get a heap corruption error when calling Set.
What am I doing wrong? (my guess is it's the way I access they array elements)

Comment: Note also that your default constructor calls array `new` with size 0. A pointer returned by that call is practically useless since dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 5 element array can be accessed at the indexes 0-4. You're passing 5 for `x` and `y`, which results in an invalid index when accessing `array`.

Comment: Damn, I totally missed that ! Thanks!

Comment: @user1233963 - If you, for some reason, wish to retain that approach (1-based), you can simply decrement the x and y before you calculate the final index for resolving an element of the array. I'd recommend zero-based, get used to it and love it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ are 0-base, that means if you have an array `int x[5]`, `x[5]` is invalid.

Your conditions should be `if( ( x<0 || x>=_n ) && ( y<0 || y>=_n) )` and `if( ( x<0 || x>=_n ) && ( y<0 || y>=_n) )`

To set the last element, you'd need

```
k.Set(4,4,6);
```

and to print it:

```
cout<<k.Get(4,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is worng is that you have to start counting from 0. If you create a array with size n*n you can acces the element up to (n-1)*(n-1). Your example create a arry of size 5*5=25 and trys to acces element 25. However 24 is the highes element you array contains.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing beyond the array into memory which is why you are getting the error.

The issue is with indexing.  The indexing of arrays in C++ starts at 0, so for your declaration of k(5), it produces an array of 5 which is indexed 0-4, so an index of 5 is not a valid valid index.  You should change your check in set to be x>=_n and y>=_n, as and index of 5 is not valid.